# Criar Lista Numérica com PHP acrescentando os 0 de 1 a 99

Tags: php

```html
$cont = 1;
<?php echo $cont++ ?>:
```

Gera uma lista como:

1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12...

Mas como deixar ela assim:

01, 02, 03, 04, 05, 06, 07, 08, 09, 10, 11, 12...

**Mas sendo assim somente quando tiver mais de 10 numeros, ou mais de 100**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usando o str_pad do php

```html
<?php echo str_pad($count_number++, 2, 0, STR_PAD_LEFT); ?>
```